# How to extract Secret key from Azure key vault in Azure Function App on Nodejs stack

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-function-app, azure-node-sdk

I have created an Azure Function app in Nodejs version 12. My hosting environment is windows. What is the easiest way to capture the username and password which are saved in Azure key vault inside my function.
Also I am using Inline code Editor so how should be capture the credentials in code.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The node SDK used in above answer is going to be deprecated and won't have new feature and releases. Instead, the new versions are released here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-secrets

Here are the detailed steps to retrieve the secret value for your reference.

**1.Enable system assigned managed identity in your function.**

[image]

**2.Add this service principal to the access policy of your key vault.**

[image]

**3.Install the dependencies to your function.**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/identity": "^1.0.3",
    "@azure/keyvault-secrets": "^4.0.4"
  }
```

**4.Here is my testing function code**

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { SecretClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-secrets");
const keyVaultName = "tonykeyvault20190801";
const KVUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
const client = new SecretClient(KVUri, credential);

const retrievedSecret = await client.getSecret("username");
const username=retrievedSecret.value;
context.log(username);
  context.res = {
      body: username 
  };
}
```

**5.The execution result.**

[image]

Comment: @VipendraSingh My pleasure

Comment: Hi @TonyJu, Is there a way to write the same code in synchronous function. When I write the code by removing the async keyword and statement without 'await' like this const retrievedSecret = client.getSecret("username"); I get the output as undefined. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It wasnot working for me, i had to do:

"Your app can’t reach the Key Vault — add your app’s IP (available under Custom domains) to your Key Vault’s firewall (under Networking)."

https://medium.com/geekculture/troubleshooting-azure-key-vault-references-in-azure-function-apps-b228c1216f63

Or else we need to use premium plan for Azure function and create a virtual network , attach our function to it. add virtual network to Key Vault’s firewall (under Networking)

Comment: link for virtual network:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet