# How to grab value from promise in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-function-app, node-async

Hi I am writing a nodejs code in Azure functions to capture the username saved in Azure key vault.
Here is the code I have written

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    var msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
    var KeyVault = require('azure-keyvault');

    function getKeyVaultCredentials() {
        return msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({
        resource: 'https://vault.azure.net/'
     });
    }

    function getKeyVaultSecret(credentials) {
        let keyVaultClient = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
        return keyVaultClient.getSecret('https://myDNS.vault.azure.net/', 'username', '');
    }


const username = getKeyVaultCredentials()
 .then(getKeyVaultSecret)
 .then(function (secret){
 context.log(`Your secret value is: ${secret.value}.`);
    return secret.value;})
 .catch(function (err) {throw (err);});

context.log(username) 
    context.res = {
        body: username 
    };
}
```

I want to capture the username but it is giving me output as

```
promise {pending}
```

How to wait for the function to end so that I can extract the username.

I am very new nodejs, please let me know what wrong I am doing and what should be the exact solution.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise describes promises very well. It will help if you read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have already used `then` to get the secret value. The value will be returned if there is no issues with the dependencies and configurations.

```
getKeyVaultCredentials()
 .then(getKeyVaultSecret)
 .then(function (secret){
 context.log(`Your secret value is: ${secret.value}.`);
    return secret.value;})
 .catch(function (err) {throw (err);});
```

But you will encounter some issues when using this sdk and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/5112) is the github issue for your reference.

It is recommended that you use the new [Azure Key Vault SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-secrets) instead. It is more convenient to use. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62528480/10504999) are the detailed steps to use **MSI** and **Key vault** in Azure function.